# How do I use Zane's 2nd action skill?

Tags: borderlands-3

Zane Flynt the Operative has the unique ability to equip 2 Action skills. How do I use the second action skill?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press the grenade key (default G on PC or LB on XBox).

> Zane can equip two Action Skills at once, though choosing to do so will replace his ability to toss grenades.

https://borderlands.com/en-US/news/2019-07-30-bl3-zane-ways-to-play/